# What vision does "the vision" in Daniel 9:23 refer to?

Tags: daniel

Daniel‬ ‭9:23‬ ‭NIV‬‬

> As soon as you began to pray, a word went out, which I have come to tell you, for you are highly esteemed. Therefore, consider the word and understand the **vision**

Question:
What vision does this refer to? Is "the vision" in 9:23 referring to the vision in Chapter 8?

‭‭Daniel‬ ‭8:27‬ ‭NIV‬‬

> I, Daniel, was worn out. I lay exhausted for several days. Then I got up and went about the king’s business. I was appalled by the **vision**; it was beyond understanding.

Comment: Use of the Hebrew word for "vision" here, on checking out the "Englishman's Concordance", centers around the word "mareh" and in our verse in question, the translit' is *"bam mar eh"*, and this is also found in **Ez 11:24; Dan,10:1**, whereas in **Dan 8:16; 8:27** we find *"(ham) mar eh"*. The difference may be subtle but nevertheless, we have a difference. Strongs 4758(e) = *mareh*, sight, appearance, vision, as Dottard points out, but his answer to my mind, is *out in left field* and believe me, it pains me to say that, he being the most consequential poster on BH, but there we are. + 1.

Answer (score 3):

Surely the question is answered within the quotation; "A word went forth and I have come to tell it to you... therefore consider the word and understand the vision" (RSV). "Considering the word" and "understanding the vision" need to be taken as synonyms, two different ways of saying the same thing. So the "vision" mentioned in this verse is the "word" that follows. That is, vv24-27, which are the response to Daniel's prayer in the first half of the chapter.

Comment: IMO, you are absolutely correct. I don't usually upvote a 3 sentence answer but I'll make an exception here.

Comment: May I clarify - how to reconcile with this? Seems contemporaneous. Daniel‬ ‭9:20‭-‬21‬: *While* I was speaking and praying, confessing my sin and the sin of my people Israel, and presenting my plea before the Lord my God for the holy hill of my God, *while* I was speaking in prayer, the man Gabriel...came to me in swift flight at the time of the evening sacrifice.

Comment: @whiskey92 - It's contemporaneous with **Daniel 9:22-23**. See my answer, just now given.

Answer (score 3):

The operative noun in Dan 9:23 is מַרְאֶה (mareh) which can refer to either:

- a sight, appearance or scene, eg, Gen 2:9, 12:11, 24:16, Dan 1:4, 13, 15, 8:15, 10:6, 18
- a supernational vision, eg, Dan 8:16, 26, 27, 9:23, 10:1.

There are two views about which vision Dan 9:23 refers to:

- the vision given in Dan 9:24:27 about the 70 weeks
- the vision given in Daniel 8 - the same word is used in Dan 8:16, 26, 27

Allow me to suggest that it is this very word that actually connects the two visions and thus makes the word (in this instance) refer to both:

Daniel 8 & 9 form a single prophetic entity amongst the four of Daniel prophecies because:

- Gabriel’s explanation was cut short and incomplete in Dan 8 because Daniel fainted with exhaustion, the prophecy was not fully explained.  Dan 8:27
- In Dan 9 the same angel, Gabriel is sent to Daniel.  Dan 9:21
- Daniel recalls the former vision of Dan 8.  Dan 9:21
- Gabriel (the same angel as the previous vision) is sent to give insight and understanding [of the former vision].  Dan 9:22
- Daniel is instructed to recall the former vision.  Dan 9:23
- The last thing mentioned in Dan 8 and the only matter left unexplained is the subject of time.  Time is the first thing mentioned in Dan 9:24 (and Dan 9:1, 2)
- Both are connected by the instruction to seal up the vision.  Dan 8:26 & 9:24.

Thus, both prophecies in these two chapters are closely linked: ch 9 is a continuation of the explanation begun in ch 8.

Comment: Wow, 4 upvotes already, and yet IMO there is so much wrong *inference* in this answer. Firstly, I don't think the two visions should be connected. Secondly, **Dan, 9:22 & 23** should not be regarded with the former vision but should surely be regarded with the latter. Thirdly, I don't see how the subject of time can be seen to connect the two visions. The former is with regard to the 2nd Cent BC alone (either 2300 days, or 1150 days), and the second covers almost 5 Centuries, 483 or 490 years (depending on ones viewpoint), commencing in 458/7 BC ... tbc ...

Comment: ... ctd ... Unlike in Ch. 8, there is no instruction, directed to Daniel, to *"seal up vision"* in Ch. 9. Ch. 9 is referring to what Jesus is to achieve.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - that is one of the differences between us in our approaches to hermeneutics - I start with the bare text and see what it says - you appear to jump too quickly to the interpretation.  If one is to use the year-day principle in Dan 9, then might it not also apply to Dan 8?

Comment: But, with all due respect, that's a nonsensical argument here. The Q. is *"What vision does 'the vision' in Daniel 9:23 refer to?"* It clearly refers to the second. See @Stephen Disraeli below.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - you were the one who raised the time prophecies.  I simply do not see it that way - not all agree with you so it is not as obvious as you might want it to be.

Comment: You were the one that brought up the subject of time. I just clarified the periods in question, in addressing what you brought up. I can't believe that you have taken this, to put it bluntly, wrong headed position. You of all people!! It's a downvote from me, which I wasn't going to give, but your continuing ?!#$ has forced my hand.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - still having trouble see another view point?  Your downvote is despite the fact that you have not pointed out any factual errors, only a difference of view point based on undisputed textual facts.

Answer (score 1):

The vision is the 70 weeks prophecy. A week is 7 years. 70×7 = 490 years. Its a prophecy about the Messiah being cut off (executed to death) but not for himself (he wasn't put to death because it was his fault, he died for other people's faults/sins) and he will be cut off before the city (jerusalem) and sanctuary (the second temple) is destroyed. This is a prophecy about Jesus Christ. He was cut off before the destruction by romans of Jerusalem and the second temple in AD 70.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There's nothing non-legit about translations like the NIV. Comments like that on this site will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

**What vision does "the vision" in Daniel 9:23 refer to?**

In the 8th Chapter and then in the 9th Chapter of Daniel, we are told of two visions, which although overlapping, as to the timing of both, are nevertheless distinct in their interpretation. The vision referenced in **Dan, 8:1-14** is with regard to the vision of the "2300 evenings and mornings", an unmistakable reference to one Antiochus Epiphanes, the *initial* "Abomination of Desolation", a Grecian king who came to the throne in 175 BC, and who subsequently oppressed the Jewish people and desecrated their temple, within a period of 2300 days from 170 BC through 164 BC, or more than likely 1150 days, specifically from Kislev (December) 15, 167 BC, through to Kislev 25, 164 BC ( as determined in the "Books of Maccabees"), but this depends on one's viewpoint, which we don't need to go into here. The angel Gabriel then interprets the vision in **Dan, 8:15-20;21-22;23-27**.

In **Dan,9:21**, reference is made to the vision *previously*, i.e. the above. But, when in **Dan,9:22,23**, where the same messenger/angel Gabriel, speaks to Daniel yet again, with regard to understanding the vision, we then have to be talking about the subsequent verses, **Dan,9:24-27**, the "70 Weeks" prophecy in actual fact, a *further* vision in other words - although not a vision per se, more of a *revelation, important *message* respecting future events - within which we find a *further*, and distinctly separate, interpretation. This prophecy encompasses almost 5 Centuries, 483 or 490 years (depending on one's viewpoint on the "70th" week), commencing in either 458, or 457 BC (7th year of Artaxerxes).

Theories abound as to the *timing* of the 70th week, but what we do know, from **Dan, 9:26**, is that the Messiah (Jesus) is cut off (crucified), after the 69th week, and that subsequent to this monumental event, the city of Jerusalem and its sanctuary are destroyed, by IMO that *second* "Abomination of Desolation", *... the people of the prince*, i.e. the Roman armies, headed by the *princely* general, namely Titus.

**Conclusion**

**Dan, 9:23**, has to be referring to the 2nd vision, if only for the fact that we have two *distinct* and *separate* interpretations, given by the angel Gabriel, which are more than a decade apart. Also, unlike in Ch.8, there is no instruction directed to Daniel, to *seal up vision*, in Ch.9. Ch.9, is referring to what Jesus is to achieve, by his death. One can speculate as to what Gabriel means by *the time of the end*, mentioned in **Dan, 8:17; & 8:26**, but to my mind, they seem to be referring to the restoration of the holy place, brought about by Judas Maccabeus, **Dan, 8:14**. 70 AD saw another end, as it were. Whereas, in **Dan, 12:4 & 12:9**, I think we are talking about a much later end time, which may, or may not, have already happened.

*revelation:- This revelation was, moreover, not communicated to Daniel in a vision, but while in the state of natural consciousness. **Keil and Delitzch**.

Also, if one was to go to - Biblehub.com - and type in **Daniel 9:23**, you can find other commentary, besides Keil and Delitzch. Commentary for instance, from the likes of Ellicott; Matthew Henry; Barnes; Gills; and Cambridge Bible for schools and colleges, where **ALL**, unequivocally stipulate, that the word "vision", heretofore mentioned, is in relation to the yet future "prophecy" of **Dan, 9:24-27**.

Comment: Thanks! There is a distinct pattern of Vision-Interpretation (by some angelic/heavenly beings) in Dan 7, 8, 10. The Visions in these chapters are filled with strong imagery and are all vividly described in the text. May I ask where is the Vision in Dan 9 please? Why is the pattern not seen here in Dan 9?

Comment: @whiskey92 - I have just edited my answer for further clarity. The "Vision" is the "70 Weeks" prophecy, without a shadow of a doubt and therefore is **not** a continuation of the vision as described and interpreted in Dan, Ch. 8.

Comment: Nice detail, well researched.  Clincher for me is in the time difference of interpretation. +1 from me.

Comment: @Thermion - *Clincher for me is in the time difference of interpretation*, hmm... I found this a difficult one to answer and maybe I didn't quite get said what needed to be said, either that or I said, speculated even, a little too much???